# Hibernate FullTextQuery, without search term?

Tags: java, hibernate, filter, lucene, hibernate-search

I am rewriting a Hibernate/lucene function, **findRangeSorting()**, that retrieves  all records in a table based on a permissions filter.  Right now this is done (very badly) by hand by stitching together HQL (hibernate sql) strings and using that to query the database.

I also have a search function which uses a better programmatic approach by creating filters for the classes using the hibernate annotation and combines Boolean queries into a full text query which then has the filters added to it based on which user is doing the search. 
(Note that is not the entire function)

`fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(bq, this.type);
            results = tab.getQueryFiltersForSearch(fullTextQuery).setSort(sort).list();`

I would like to use this functionality for the **findRangeSorting()** function since the filters are already in place, so I would basically just need to have the search return everything. The downside is that searching for "" and * don't accomplish this, and so I need to basically create a *FullTextQuery* without having to search for an actual term, or possibly **find an alternative method for retrieving a range of rows from a table with filters based on user permissions**.

I do not have the best grasp of hibernate so I might be totally wrong in my assumptions.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a query match all documents, you should just be able to use Lucene's [`MatchAllDocsQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html).  I'm not aware of anything in the Hibernate `QueryBuilder` that creates a `MatchAllDocsQuery`, but it's simple enough to create one through the Lucene API directly, something like:

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query allQuery = new org.apache.lucene.search.MatchAllDocsQuery();
fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(allQuery, this.type); 
results = tab.getQueryFiltersForSearch(fullTextQuery).setSort(sort).list();
```